# creating new application in IIS 7 can cause other applications running on same IIS to log out?

Tags: iis-7

I am new to IIS 7 and i am running a 16 user Application Server

i received complains from my colleagues that their application log out suddenly and not saving edits. i compared the time of complains and they match the time when i was trying to install a new asp.net application or modify an existing one (of course not the very one they complained from)

does this make sense? i mean are these events (application crash and installing new application on IIS) related together.

note that i did not restart IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have touched web.config file of an existing ASP.NET Web Site then the appDomain recycles. Check this [link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx) and [link 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2005/12/01/499144.aspx)